# How do I get the brand name from the eBay Trading API?

Tags: python, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I am using Trading API (eBay Python SDK) to extract the product name, pictures and also its price. However I have some difficulties in extracting the brand name and the description (condition, material, authenticity, etc).

Is there a way to extract the brand name and the description?

Answer (score 1):

Using **GetItem** and **GetSellerList** API you can get all listing details.

1.**GetItem**

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItem.html#GetItem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>ABC...123</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <ItemID>110043671232</ItemID>
</GetItemRequest>
```

In GetItem API you need to just pass eBay Item id , API will return all product details.

2.**GetSellerList**

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetSellerList.html#GetSellerList

Using GetSellerList API we can get information product name and other details.

You must pass date range start date-end date and difference must not be greater then 90 days.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetSellerListRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>ABC...123</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
<GranularityLevel>Coarse</GranularityLevel> 
<StartTimeFrom>2016-02-12T21:59:59.005Z</StartTimeFrom> 
<StartTimeTo>2016-02-26T21:59:59.005Z</StartTimeTo> 
<IncludeWatchCount>true</IncludeWatchCount> 
<Pagination> 
    <EntriesPerPage>2</EntriesPerPage> 
</Pagination>
```

This may help you.

Comment: When i use getItem, not all the results give me the brand name. Some of them does not have the BrandMPN although I have use the DetailLevel: ItemReturnAttributes.

Comment: Brand & MPN number is not required in eBay.It may be possible in some products both attributes are not set, you can login in account & check value.

Comment: But usually if you see the details on the description tab, there is a box with the title item specifics and in that box, there is information about color, brand and any other important info. However, this box is not retrieved if I call getItem. Is there a way to get those information?

Comment: You should use GetItem API, it will give you all attribute values.http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItem.html#GetItem